Are integer multiples of a frequency in an FFT necessarily in phase?
I performed a FFT on a signal and the most prominent frequency at about 0.5 cycles/time only makes up about 6% of the total frequency distribution, which is pretty low for my purposes, so I was wondering about combining that bin with the bins for integer multiples of that frequency (1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5...). My thinking was that they would constructively interfere and boost the 6% signal to something higher, but these integer multiple frequencies aren't necessarily in phase are they? Is there a way to determine their relative phase shift from an FFT? My guess is no, but thought I'd ask.

What are your “purposes”?

I'd like to determine how likely a peak or a trough is if I extrapolate my historical data into the future, so if my FFT's most prominent frequency is only 6% of the signal, then that frequency's peak or trough is not very likely to occur, but if I add together the harmonics and if they're in phase then I can increase the probability of predicting when they might constructively interfere in the future...if that makes any sense....

If your signal is periodic but not a sine wave, than this might help. Every periodic function will have energy at the fundamental and it's integer multiples (the harmonics). Note that the fundamental does not necessarily has the highest energy. In fact, it can have no energy at all. It's the spacing between the harmonics.

but these integer multiple frequencies aren't necessarily in phase are they

Depends in the shape of your signal but generally they are not in phase. You can just sum them in energy (sum the magnitude squares).

Is there a way to determine their relative phase shift from an FFT?

Of course. It's just the angle difference between the two complex numbers.

That might be helpful, but I don't know how periodic my data is because it's market data, so its periodicity is not exact. It's noisy. Would that be an issue?
